Creating a Flutter screen with SmoothPageIndicator, a grid of selectable options, and non-swipeable PageView
I'm developing a Flutter screen that serves as an onboarding page where users provide information about themselves. I'm facing several challenges with its implementation:
1. SmoothPageIndicator Issue:
At the top of the screen, I've integrated SmoothPageIndicator to show progress as the user navigates through different pages using a PageView. However, I'm encountering an issue where the indicator behaves like a progress bar, highlighting all pages that the user has visited instead of just indicating the current page. How can I modify SmoothPageIndicator to achieve the desired behavior?
2. Grid of Selectable Options:
Below the SmoothPageIndicator, I have a grid layout displaying various options that users can select. Users can choose multiple options, and I want to differentiate between selected and unselected options by changing their colors accordingly. How can I implement this functionality in Flutter?
3. Non-swipeable PageView:
Additionally, I'd like to restrict the PageView from being swipeable. Instead, users should navigate to the next page using a button located at the bottom of the screen. What's the best approach to achieve this behavior in Flutter?
I want the screen to look exactly like this:
Please how do I achieve this?

For making pageview not Swipeble, set it's physics as NeverScrollableScrollPhysics. And for indicator issue - use onPageChanged fn of pageview. Start progress with zero and on page change set the progress as index of pageview. For grid item maintain a list of selected item. On item click add it in list. And check if item exist in list set it's color as green, if not then black color.

Or you can use package like this onboarding: ^4.0.2.
